# CSS: Label/Input wont float in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am having problems with floating a label and input next to each other in IE7. I have tried everything I can think of:

- Giving it a fixed width
- Overflow hidden,border, background.
- Wrapping inside of a div with float left.

The only way I can get it to work correctly is if I put it inside a table.

Comment: this is IE9 in the screenshot

Comment: Yes, the compatibility view button is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make a clearing div under each row.

Like

```
<label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username"/>
<div class="clear"></div>  
<label>Password</label><input type="text" name="password"/>
<div class="clear"></div>

.clear {
clear:both;
}
```